# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection - chart databind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, charts

I'm trying to build a datatable and then bind it to a gridview and chart object. The gridview appears fine but when I build the x,y array and bind them to the chart object I get the error above.

I've read many forums to understand that the index is looking at a field that is out of range but I've queried in the immediate window all the fields and the are clearly values there. There error occurs as soon as I bind it to the chart object and I don't know why the chart object doesn't just display properly.

This is my aspx codebehind:

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("CompanyName")
        dt.Columns.Add("Amount")
        dt.Columns.Add("Proportion")
        Using DBContext As New fundmatrixEntities
            Dim queryUnits = (From c In DBContext.Units Where c.SavingApplicationId = savAppId Select New With {.LoanAppId = c.LoanApplicationId}).Distinct().ToList()

            Dim companyName As String = ""
            Dim savingsAmount As String = ""
            Dim totalProportion As String = ""
            Dim totalSavingsAmount As String = ""

            For Each loan In queryUnits
                If Not loan.LoanAppId Is Nothing Then
                    companyName = classSQLDirect.ExecQuery("SELECT companyname FROM companyprofile where loanapplicationid='" & loan.LoanAppId.ToString & "'")
                    savingsAmount = classSQLDirect.ExecQuery("SELECT SUM(Amount) from unit where SavingApplicationId='" & savAppId.ToString & "' and LoanApplicationId='" & loan.LoanAppId.ToString & "'")
                    totalSavingsAmount = classSQLDirect.ExecQuery("SELECT amount FROM SavingApplication WHERE SavingApplicationId='" & savAppId.ToString & "'")
                    totalProportion = ((savingsAmount / totalSavingsAmount) * 100) & "%"

                    dt.Rows.Add(companyName, savingsAmount, totalProportion)
                End If
            Next
            gvwBusinesses.DataSource = dt
            gvwBusinesses.DataBind()

        End Using

        Dim x As String() = New String(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        Dim y As String() = New String(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            x(i) = dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
            y(i) = dt.Rows(i)(2).ToString()
        Next
        chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(x, y)
        chart1.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
```

The code errors on the line

```
chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(x, y)
```

Comment: How many elements are in the `Series` collection on `chart1`?  (Hint: none)  The code expects at least one element to be there.  Where does `chart1` come from and what should be populating that collection?  (It's not shown in the code.)

Comment: You are right. I didn't realise you need to define the series beforehand. Thanks for you hint.